# Knitr: Only chunk output is html (rest stays rmarkdown)

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am trying to make a knitr-based program that reads rmarkdown from a character vector and writes to a textConnection.  I am getting almost what I want but I find that knitr only produces html for chunks and just passes through the rmarkdown to html.

Here is the code:

````
text_input <- "Title
========================================================

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring web pages (click the **MD** toolbar button for help on Markdown).

When you click the **Knit HTML** button a web page will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cache=TRUE}
x <- cars
summary(x)
```

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r fig.width=7, fig.height=6,cache=TRUE}
plot(x)
```
"
library(knitr)

outfile <- textConnection("foo.html", "w")

pat_md()
render_html()
knit(input=NULL,output=outfile,text=text_input)
close(outfile)
cat(foo.html,sep="\n")
````

Which outputs:

```
Title
========================================================

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring web pages (click the **MD** toolbar button for help on Markdown).

When you click the **Knit HTML** button a web page will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

<div class="chunk" id="unnamed-chunk-1"><div class="rcode"><div class="source"><pre class="knitr r">x <- cars
summary(x)
</pre></div><div class="output"><pre class="knitr r">##      speed           dist    
##  Min.   : 4.0   Min.   :  2  
##  1st Qu.:12.0   1st Qu.: 26  
##  Median :15.0   Median : 36  
##  Mean   :15.4   Mean   : 43  
##  3rd Qu.:19.0   3rd Qu.: 56  
##  Max.   :25.0   Max.   :120
</pre></div></div></div>


You can also embed plots, for example:

<div class="chunk" id="unnamed-chunk-2"><div class="rcode"><div class="source"><pre class="knitr r">plot(x)
</pre></div><div class="rimage default"><img src="figure/unnamed-chunk-2.png" title="plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-2" alt="plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-2" class="plot" /></div>
</div></div>
```

Is this the expected behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this a different way (create md file with knitr and then md -> html):

```
text_input <- "markdown text"
library(knitr)

foo.html <- knit2html(text=text_input)
```

Thanks Yihui.  However as I note in the comment below there are still some issues with the resulting html (only with character vector input not regular files).

Comment: that is what `knit2html()` does: `knit2html(text = text_input)`

Comment: Actually now I am trying to decide whether to create a followup question. The output from this works great for regular files, but for text input there are problems if the character vector contains linebreaks "\n". Basically the resulting html string has lots of "\n" that appear to cause some html parsing problems.

Comment: You only _see_ `\n` on the screen, but that is not literally a backslash followed by `n` -- it is a linebreak. You do not need to parse anything. That character string is what you want. You can write it to a file using, for example, `cat()`. If you give `knit2html()` a text input, and you will get a text output. If you give it an input file, you get an output file.

Comment: Got it.  Yeah copying the string from RStudio is the wrong thing to do in this case.  After I tested this in the intended domain (a Shiny app) all is well.  Thanks again for the basic help.